# Animated gallery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, onmouseover, onmouseout

I trying to build function which will change the pictures on "onmouseover" event without page refresh, but doesn't work.

```js
<script>

i = 0;

function foto_start() {
 x = ["image2", "image3", "image4"];
 y = document.getElementById("1").src;  
 
    //loop replace in string "image1" on "image2", "image3" ...
 while(1) { 
  z = y.replace("image1", x[i]);
  
  setTimeout(new_image(), 1000);
  
        //if the last element in array, set i = 0 else increase
  if(x[i] == "image4")
   i = 0;
  else
   i++;
 }
}

function new_image() {
 document.getElementById("1").src = z;
}

function foto_stop() {
 document.getElementById("1").src = "http://example.com/image1.jpg";
}

</script>
```

```html
// element HTML to modify
<img id="1" onmouseover="foto_start()" onmouseout="foto_stop()" src="http://example.com/image1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for that complicated stuff, you can just put a parameter in the `foto_start()` method:

```
function foto_start(imageSrc){
    document.getElementById('1').src=imageSrc;
}

<img id="1" onmouseover="foto_start('http://example.com/image2.jpg')" onmouseout="foto_stop()" src="http://example.com/image1.jpg" />
```